# Get-ADUser return a single account from all OU's and Sub OU's

Tags: active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I have the following sample OU structure in my Active Directory server

[image: MY-OU-STRUCTURE]
I have user accounts in the "users" OU in each of OU1, OU2 and so on.
The user accounts have a static prefix e.g. OU1 will have user accounts like OU1user1,OU1user2,OU1user3 and so on. Similarly OU2 and OU3 will have use accounts like OU2user2,OU2user2,OU2user3 & OU3user1,OU3user2,OU3user3

Now what I want?

I want only a single user (it can be any user) from all of the OU's under the RootOU. Currently i am using the following command and its returning all the users inside the RootOU's sub-OU.

```html
$ou = "OU=RootOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com"
$myUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter *  -SearchBase $ou -SearchScope 2
```

Comment: This doesn't sound logical to me! Your question should likely be *which specific user would you like to search for within the OUs* (based on name, sAMAccountName, other parameters)?

Comment: There are close to 50,000 users in various OU, so it cannot be specific user. From every OU  i am trying to get a single user to extract the naming pattern as i am then using it to do something else. This i  doing to optimize an already working script but its unnecessarily running longer than required as it ends up processing all the accounts which is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do something like

```
$myUsers = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '*users*'" -SearchBase $ou -SearchScope 2 | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object -First 1
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the idea. I had to make a slight change otherwise it went in a loop.               $allusers = @(foreach ($userou in $ou.distinguishedname) 
                    {

                        Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $userou | Select-Object -First 1 
    
                    }
              )